# Why would Linux waste bytes for tracking unused pages?

Tags: linux-kernel, mips

From the file /vobs/linux/kernel/linux/arch/mips/kernel/setup.c (Linux 2.6.30)

```
    pr_info("Wasting %lu bytes for tracking %lu unused pages\n",
        (min_low_pfn - ARCH_PFN_OFFSET) * sizeof(struct page),
        min_low_pfn - ARCH_PFN_OFFSET);
```

This line prints

```
Wasting 64 bytes for tracking 2 unused pages
```

On my device during boot. What does it actually mean? Why are those bytes wasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an array of `struct page` structures, one for each page in physical lowmem.

This message is shown because the memory map provided by the bootloader has reserved the first two pages in your physical memory - those pages will never be used, but there's still two corresponding `struct page` structures for them.

I wouldn't worry about it, 64 bytes is pretty trivial.